# Instalador de serviço C# com ações personalizadas

Tags: c#, windows, instalador

Estou fazendo um serviço em C#, e quero criar um instalador. Segui alguns tutorias, e achei o setup do Visual Studio meio basicão.

Alguma sugestão de como fazer um instalador bonito com Visual Studio?

Comment: Use o WIX. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b6868002-9770-4479-80a7-259de34df527?SRC=VSIDE Veja um tutorial que escrevi aqui http://blogdoquintal.net/2015/01/02/criando-um-instalador-para-windows-service-com-wix/ Qualquer dúvida deixe um comentário no blog ou mande um email para mapquintal@yahoo.com.br

Comment: Uso muito o Inno Setup, bem customizável, bonito e simples.

Comment: Pode especificar melhor seus requisitos? "Basicão" e "bonito" são conceitos subjetivos demais.

Comment: @bfavaretto e em geral acabam virando coisas desastrosas, fugindo completamente do esquema visual do OS.